React Three.js unable to display the mesh with apropriate texture
I exported a glb file from blender. It has texture applied. But when I load it on web through R3F, it looks too much exposed and texture is very weird and low quality with no color. But when I load this in  gltf Viewer it looks perfect. Below is the output images and code.
Output Images:
React Three Js output

Gltf Viewer Output

import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useGLTF, Stage, PresentationControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import { useCreateAvatarStore } from "../store/store";

function Model(props) {
    const avatarUrl = useCreateAvatarStore(state => state.garmentAvatarVariable.avatar_url);
    const { scene } = useGLTF(`http://localhost:8080/${avatarUrl}`);
    return <primitive object={scene} {...props} />;
} 

export default function DressedAvatar() {
    return (
        <Canvas
            dpr={[2, 2]}
            camera={{ fov: 45 }}
            style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
            gl={{ toneMapping: 0, exposure: 0 }}
        >
            <ambientLight intensity={0.3} />
            <directionalLight intensity={2.5} />
            <color attach="background" args={["#808080"]} />
            <PresentationControls speed={1.5} global zoom={0.5} polar={[-0.1, Math.PI / 4]}>
                <Stage environment={null}>
                    <Model scale={0.01} />
                </Stage>
            </PresentationControls>
        </Canvas>
    );
}


